# Copy url from post_content to custom field

Tags: custom-field, mysql, post-content

I'm new to MySQL so I don't know if this is even possible.

I would like to copy a url that's in post_content to a custom field. The url is variable and it looks like this:

```
[audio:http://www.website.com/folder/file.mp3]
```

Is it possible to copy just the url (http://www.website.com/folder/file.mp3) to a custom field?

I've tried different things but as I don't always understand how to query MySQL I've had no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is run a function that gets triggered when the "update" button is clicked on posts.

I can't guarantee that my attempt to isolate the shortcode was successful, ( I'm not too good at that stuff ), but you definitely get the idea here!

```
add_action('save_post', 'save_details');
function save_details() {
    global $post;

    if(get_post_type($post->ID) == 'your_custom_post_type') {
      if(stripos($post->post_content, '[audio:http://') !== false) { // if shortcode exists
        $content = $post->post_content;

        //first position of shortcode
        $p1 = stripos($content, '[audio:http://');

        // strip code from before the shortcode.
        $content = substr($content, $p1);

        //find when end of the shortcode starts
        $p2 = stripos($content, '.mp3]');
        $p2 = $p2 + 5;  // add five to get where it ends.

        //get full shortcode
        $content = substr($content, 0, $p2);

        // save shortcode to meta field
        update_post_meta($post->ID, 'custom_field_name', $content);
    }
   }
}
```

Let me know if you have any troubles!